# Why can't I insert a DVD into my Mac Mini?

Tags: macos, windows, hardware, mac-mini

I'm trying, without success, to insert a DVD inside my Mac mini DVD drive. Let me say that actually the computer is without the upper case and the HD drive has been taken from a Windows laptop (it is NTFS formatted and there's Windows XP installed on it).

I'm tryng to insert Install DVD to format and reinstall a proper version of Mac OS X upon new hard drive, but I can't.

Comment: What is happening when you attempt to insert the DVD in the drive? Is there a physical barrier, is it accepting the disk and then spitting it back out? More details please!

Comment: Yes, it seems to enter almost completly, but at the moment in which computer should pull the disk inside, the disk is bounced back.

Comment: At what point in the boot process does this occur? Are you holding a particular key on startup?

Comment: As I said before, Windows XP is installed on the HD, so as soon as boot start the folder with question mark appears.
No, no key pressed.

Comment: Just so you are aware It's a violation of the OSX license agreement to install OSX on non apple hardware - your windows laptop HD.

Comment: @GraemeHutchison There's nothing against the license to install OS X on a hard drive that isn't from Apple if you're using that drive with an Apple Computer. If you're using a Mac Mini, that's the Apple hardware.

Comment: Obviously purchasing a copy of Mac OS X is required to legally run the OS, currently the license agreement only allows installing on 'Apple Hardware' but this is being brought before the courts as unfair so until the dust settles you may be breaking the license agreement. (quote from biline on using OSX) the agreement specifies non apple labeled computers. So there is a bit of a shady bit there.

Comment: Forget anything about new hard drive! I just want to repair my old mac for free, i'm not really intersted in legal problem.
I have a hard-drive available (zero costs) and a legally purchased Mac OSX, that's matter.

Comment: @Mariano use a thumb drive install. Available from Apple.

Comment: Resolved: Every problem has gone away as soon I've closed my computer with upper case. I don't know there was a chip to control this issue!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your optical drive is faulty, immediate ejection of a disk is typical of an optical drive failure.

In the current state your Mac mini is trying to boot to a Macintosh volume.  So, after pressing the power button press and hold the `Option` key until a mouse cursor appears and your Windows XP partition should appear.  Using either arrow keys and the `Enter` key, or the mouse, you can select the Windows XP partition and boot to that.

In terms of getting your optical drive fixed, I'd recommend buying an external USB optical drive, it'd be much cheaper than repairing your optical drive through the Apple channels.

Comment: Windows XP is installed on a NTFS partition. Can Mini loads it without problem?

Comment: Nothing happen' holding shift key :(

Comment: Resolved: Every problem has gone away as soon I've closed my computer with upper case. I don't know there was a chip to control this issue!

Comment: Sorry!  I wrote Shift instead of Option.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the PRAM by holding down the <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> keys after pressing the power button. Keep holding it until you hear your startup chime twice. Then, hold down the alt/option key while booting and see if the DVD shows up as a boot option then.

Comment: I can't hear chime. Holding that keys just cause a sort of continuous reboot. :\

Comment: UPDATE: if with computer still open, I gently touch the optical drive it start to rotate, even without DVD/CD inside.

Comment: Resolved: Every problem has gone away as soon I've closed my computer with upper case. I don't know there was a chip to control this issue!